# How to correctly test file's extension in if statement?

Tags: test

Just an illustration:

first

```
cd /usr/lib
```

and run

```
for x in $(ls);do if [ "$x" == "*.a" ];then echo $x;fi;done
```

What I want to do is to select files with extension .a and print them. I know there are much simpler way of doing this, but that is not my intention here.

The problem is that the command above doesn't work. I don't know why. I learn this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/407334/1911722)

I also tried

```
[ "$x" == *.a ]    bash: [: too many arguments
[ $x = "*.a" ]    shows nothing
[ $x = *.a ]    bash: [: too many arguments
```

I know `[[ $x == *.a ]]` works, but I want to know what is the correct way to write `[` test in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for x in ./*; do
   case $x in
      *".a" ) echo "$x";;
   esac
done
```

The `[` construct  is not exactly suited for this. But if you insist, we may do it like as follows:

```
[ '.a'  =  ".${x##*.}" ]
```

## Explanation

Say $x contains: `my.file.testing.a` Then `${x##*.}` will , starting from the left, strip away as much as it can till the last `.` it manages to see in `$x`. IOW, we end up dropping everything and bringing the `extension` viz, `a` to the fore. So now we have the extension we just computed to compare against what we think it better be(`.a`) for success.

Comment: Hi, Rakesh Sharma. Thank you for answering. But could you please explain the last line a bit?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked to in your question uses bash's (double-bracket) *extended test syntax*, whereas you are trying to use the POSIX single-bracket test operator. The difference is that in the double-bracket test, the right hand side of an `==` is treated as a pattern rather than being subject to word splitting or glob expansion. So whereas `[ $f == *.a ]` results in the `[: too many arguments` error, you **may** do

```
for f in *; do if [[ $f == *.a ]]; then echo "$f"; fi; done
```

or (more compactly)

```
for f in *; do [[ $f == *.a ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

Alternatively, since you appear to be using `bash`, you could use the `=~` regular expression operator e.g.

```
for f in *; do if [[ $f =~ \.a$ ]]; then echo "$f"; fi; done
```

or (more compactly)

```
for f in *; do [[ $f =~ \.a$ ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

although it's overkill in this case.

Comment: Oh, my god. After reading that linked answer again. I found I misinterpreted the author. Thank you for answering, expecially for mentioning the overkill `=~` syntax